# CiviCalendar: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated

Tags: php, calendar

I'm trying to prepare a site for migration to a new host, and the copy of the site I've set up on the new host is generating masses of warnings that I'm not seeing on the current production environment.

In Drupal's recent log messages I see line after line of:

```
Deprecated function: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in require_once() (line 3 of /home/username/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civicalendar/calendar.php).
```

Then I also have a file called error_log that has appeared in the Drupal root with the following at five minute increments (that is, every time cron runs):

```
PHP Deprecated:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /home/username/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civicalendar/calendar.civix.php on line 257
```

Drupal 7.92, CiviCRM 5.54.0, CiviCalendar 3.5.1. The old host was still on PHP 7.3, whereas this one is 7.4, so I'm assuming it's to do with that, but is there a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a PR at https://github.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.civicalendar/pull/27. You can try it and if it works for you then comment on that PR and hopefully it will get merged and they'll make a new release.

Comment: No new errors for half an hour after integrating that, so I guess it's worked. Thanks!